# Sending Emails on a particular day

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, oracle

I'm developing a web page (asp.net, C#), where the users enter some data every month and save it. I use oracle database.

If the data is not entered for a month, I want a mail to be sent to some email ID, ie. *myid@abc.com*.

Can anyone help me doing this?

Comment: It might be better if you'd show *some* effort in trying to do it yourself...

Comment: You can create a windows service and let that service check data everyday and send emails accordingly.

Comment: Or a Web service with scheduled task, WCF service etc. Pick any method that meet your requirements.

Comment: Thank You so much for the replies. I'm new into Developing. Do not know  about sending Emails. I will try with your  suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given how vague your question is, here is an answer to match - use [Oracle Alerts](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18727_01/doc.121/e12951/T338646T338655.htm).

This [blog article](http://oraclemaniac.com/2012/03/24/send-emails-with-oracle-alerts/) should put you in the right direction.